# Mirroring failed over - created 2 principal database and will not allow me to drop one of them

Tags: sql-server-2012, mirroring

For some reason my mirrored servers triggered an automatic failover. I have 2 databases that both think they are the principal server, one is "Principal, Synchronized/In Recovery" and the other is "Principal, Synchronizing"

I figure this is bad. My plan is to rebuild mirroring by dropping the database on one server and restoring it again based on the backup of the other. I have removed mirroring on one of the servers. And took a backup. However, I cannot drop the database on the other server. I have tried single user mode, detaching and taking database offline.

I have tried to kill process using this database but it doesn't work. The command it is on is "KILLED/ROLLBACK" but nothing changes here.

Comment: This is commonly referred to as "split brain" - see [this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/discussionofsqlserver/2014/05/22/avoiding-a-split-brain-in-database-mirroring/) and [this](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2010/04/16/mirroring-what-happens-if-principal-loses-contact-with-both-mirror-and-wittness.aspx) for some ideas...

Comment: Sadly I just solved this problem with a reboot of the server. The databases became Mirror/Synchronized after reboot. Sigh...though I'm glad it's fixed, it's not the solution I was hoping for

Comment: @Dina did you perfectly removed the mirroring before dropping database. I mean using alter query to set partner off and then bringing mirror DB online?

Comment: Yes - at which point the database for which I removed mirroring entered "principal, disonnected" state, this one I attempted to delete and failed. Another database in similar situation (for which I did not try to remove mirroring) reverted to being mirror, synchronized instead.